# Why does Bane say "the fire rises"?

Tags: tense, present-tense

In the very beginning of the movie, (the airplane scene) when Bane is about to leave the plane with the nuclear scientist, the following dialogue takes place between Bane and one of his men:

> Bane: No, they'll expect one of us in the wreckage, brother.
>
> Man: Have we started the fire?
>
> Bane: Yes, **the fire rises**.

I wonder why Bane says it rather than **the fire has risen** or **the fire rose** or **the fire is rising**. Why use the simple present tense there?

Comment: I believe this might be implied to be a part of a code or code phrase.  In this case, as part of their bond in the group rather than to hide information from some outsider.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's a reference to the title of the movie, "The Dark Knight Rises."  Present tense here is nearly the same as present progressive (is rising).  However, the present tense gives the impression that the action a little more immediate than present progressive -- present progressive gives the impression that it's a gradual and ongoing sort of process.  Thus, it sounds a little more dramatic in present tense, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The villain Bane is pretentious and wishes to sound portentous.

Comment: +1, but it would be great to have more explanation and/or backing around how the simple present mood relates to a style characteristic of portents.

Comment: That would get into the interface between usage and literary criticism, which I understand to be off-topic. ;-)

Comment: Indeed. Touché!

Comment: As a learner, OP doesn't have enough knowledge of English; you might want to elaborate on it. Your answer may be obvious to native speakers, but not to other future visitors. Although it's not compulsory, more elaboration would help it. Otherwise, this post will lose its significance. @TimRomano

Comment: Let's say father and daughter are watching a rosebud in their garden for a few days. He goes out of town on a business trip and phones home. Daughter tells him excitedly, "The rose is blooming!". A native speaker uses the progressive form "is {verb}ing" to state that something is happening now. "The fire's rising" would be the normal way to say the fire is beginning to burn more intensely. Tone of voice could make it a dramatic statement: "The fire's *rising*!". To use the simple present tense "rises" suggests a degree of detachment from the action, in Bane's case, a cold-bloodedness.

Comment: What's meant by "detachment from the action"? And what is the drama effect? @Tim

Comment: Psychological detachment.  The dramatic effect (characterization) is one of extreme emotional numbness; Bane is a psychopath, after all.

Comment: Point taken! But as Tyler suggested, how does the simple present mood relate to a style characteristic of portents? I don't understand it. Does this imply he's just an onlooker, not an evil-doer? @Tim

Comment: Detached emotionally is not the same as being "just an onlooker". Sociopaths may not feel, but that does not imply that they do not act.

Answer (score 1):

The film's plot was inspired by the Charles Dickens novel "A Tale of Two Cities." Several of the film's motifs (as well as part of its ending) are taken from the novel, and the novel is quoted at the end of the film. One of the chapters in "A Tale of Two Cities" is titled "Fire Rises." My belief is that this line is an allusion to this chapter.

However, within the context of the film, the line merely sounds more dramatic and mysterious when he says it in this tense. It is precisely because it does not sound natural that it has this effect.

Answer (score 0):

It is a reference to A Tale of Two Cities. The chapter plan Dickens filed in his book lists Fire Rises. Also, Barsad, a character in A Tale Of Two Cities is the name of the big man's right hand man.

Answer (score -1):

It's a reference to a chapter in *A Tale of Two Cities* upon which *The Dark Knight Rises* is loosely based.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? Your premise is interesting; your answer could be improved if you included the Dickens quote and maybe even an excerpt from a literary review that supporting assertion that _Dark Knight_ is loosely based on _Two Cities._ (not my downvote, btw)

Answer (score -1):

I would not expect an aggressive terrorist to speak in passive voice - 
"Fire is rising". Leaders speak with more authority when active voice is used - "the fire rises".

Comment: But *Fire is rising* is not in passive voice!